# When I click back button dropdown not going back

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

When I click back button dropdown not going back. But gridview data going back. Corresponding dropdown not changed properly. I try:

```
    function Back() {
        GetPriviousValue();
        history.go(-1);

        return false;
    }
```

Above this code, dropdown not go back when I click back button, but grid page go back. So I tried cache. That code is:

```
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

But this code produce Document Expired page in firefox. How to get dropdown go back properly when I click back button? Is possible to any jquery?

Comment: What does it mean that "dropdown not going back"?, please clarify what is not working as expected. history.go(-1) is just like pressing the back button in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well this happens because when you go back the browser displays you the page in the same state that you have left it. And you left it after selecting a value from dropdown.

To mitigate this problem take the help of javascript/jquery. Declare a hiddenfield and set its value in page load with the value of selected dropdown value.

in bodyload event javascript select the dropdown value from hiddenfield.

alernatively you may call form.reset method in body load event.

Comment: Till i have this problem.can u give me proper code..I search lot.But i cant get solution.